# python setup.py install doesn't work properly on alpine image

Tags: python, docker, setuptools, alpine-linux, python-packaging

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine3.6

ENV PORT 5000
ENV APP  /usr/src
ENV FLASK_APP pkg_name/app.py

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add build-base postgresql-dev git gcc
RUN apk add musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev

ADD . /
RUN python setup.py install
# RUN pip install .

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD flask run
```

the configuration above work perfectly in standard python image but not in alpine image. Both `python setup.py install` or `pip install .` will install the package correctly but when I run `flask run` it complain that the installed module is not found:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pkg_name/app.py", line 6, in <module>
     from pkg_name.api import api 
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_name'
```

Running `pip freeze` shows that the project in the list of installed packages. Trying to import the project in the python interpreter `>>> import pkg_name` works also fine, which is weird.

**Question:**

Does any one has an explanation why the pkg could not be imported on run time despite it's installed and imported correctly in the interpeter. How can I fix it.

Comment: I created a [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/six8/41d5f2fd59e7f5ed87dc10e8f250d91c) and did not have issues running this. Is something possibly wrong with your setup.py? If you run Python interpreter in the container can you `import pkg_name`?

Comment: `pkg_name/app.py` is found. It's `from pkg_name.api import api` that is failing.

Comment: If you run Python interpreter in the container can you `from pkg_name.api import api`?

Comment: @six8 as explained above `from pkg_name.api import api` works fine in the interpreter. In you example you are not doing explicit import such `from pkg_name.api import api`.

Comment: I tried `from pkg_name.api import api` in `app.py` in my example after I posted it. The result is still the same, no issue. Above you say only `import pkg_name` was tried in interpreter -- not `from pkg_name.api import api`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that worked for me was setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Still feel is just a dirty workaround, because the site-packages path is in the `sys.path` and the packages are correctly installed there, but for now it solved the issue.